# It is not possible to build a project with the android module connected

Tags: android, gradle

There is an Android module that I use in this project that I want to use in the main module of my application. It was possible to connect, but during data collection it gives an error that dependent functions are configured, but the package ID was not set.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':otherapi')
}
```

Where to specify this ID or how to solve the problem so that the build is successful? I want to use this otherapi module in my other applications